# How to make the code inside a powershell loop run asynchrously?

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, synchronous

so I have a loop, and I send a request to an API endpoint inside of a for loop until there are no 'results' left. After each Invoke-RestMethod is called, the next one that is called returns the next set of results. This is for data collection, so the parsing through the response returned by each request doesn't have to be done synchronously. How can I make it so that Each Invoke-RestMethod (these take from 1-2 seconds) is called in the correct order, but do the data parsing for each response (takes about 20 seconds total) be done asynchronously in the function as a whole? Call order would look something like this:

Invoke-RestMethod1 (after results are returned, immediately start going through this 'response 1')
Invoke-RestMethod2 (after results are returned, immediately start going through this 'response 2')
...
Invoke-RestMethodN (after results are returned, immediately start going through this 'response N')

My loop looks like this:

```
while ($true) {
        # querying the endpoint to get the results
        $query = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://my_api_endpoint.com' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
        # handling the response returned by this iteration of the query
        [PSCustomObject]$latestItems = $query.items
        if ($latestItems -ne @()) {
            foreach ($item in $latestItems) {
                try {
                    $item.source | Export-Csv $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Host "Failed"
                } 
            }
        }
        else {
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how async and "is called in the correct order" can go together

Comment: I was thinking if I added some kind of delay after the Invoke-RestMethod (say 5 seconds), that would give it enough time to complete before moving on to the next iteration's Invoke-RestMethod and processing of the first one. Also, just in general maybe just making the whole inner part of the loop async would do the trick, I'd need to test that. @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: It may but also it may not.

Comment: How would I set up the loop in that case? @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: @helpaccount321 You'll want to kick off a background job or separate runspace to continuously probe a collection for input, then process it, _before entering the loop_ - then inside the loop, simply write the data from the HTTP response to the collection and let the background job pick it up while loop continues

Comment: You could start jobs or runspaces and wait for them and receive them in order based on the job's name, that's totally ok. However by looking at your code, it's unclear how you're querying your API, there is a `while($true)` sending the same query to the API so the same response should be received

Comment: The way the endpoint works, the same query is sent to the endpoint and each one returns some new results. If I don't need anything to be in a specific order (totally asynchronous), what's the best approach?

Comment: If one query depends on the previous one I don't believe this can be made async. Not sure honestly.

Comment: One query does NOT depend on the previous query. I'm pretty unfamiliar with Powershell so am having trouble with this. I tried wrapping the query and the if block below it inside a Start-Job -ScriptBlock (with that block of code going in as the argument, but the Export-Csv lines (or even Write-Host) don't seem to work when this runs as a background job. @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: Update the question showing the `Start-Job` implementation, if I see something wrong I'll help you figure it out